# Calling a local Service Fabric stateless API using the Service Fabric url

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

Does anyone know if I can make HTTP calls to the API endpoint of a local Service Fabric cluster using "fabric:/my-fabric-app/api-service" directly, without going through an HTTP listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. The `fabric:/` endpoints are intended for [SF Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting) calls. 
For using HTTP, an [HTTP Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore) is required.

Comment: I wonder how Azure API Management does it when you set up fabric service as a back end to API defined in API management. The back end is fabric:/ endpoint and was trying to replicate same setup for some testing